# Jquery - Position of dynamically appended element

Tags: jquery, append

.appendI'm trying to get the position().top of dynamically appended element.

Firstly, I have a function to create the element

```
var createElement = function (elementType, id, name, className, innerText) {

    var el = document.createElement(elementType);
    if (id)         {el.id          = id;} 
    if (name)       {el.name        = name;}
    if (className)  {el.className   = className;}
    if (innerText) el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(innerText));}

    return el;           
}
```

to add an element....

```
$('#parent').append(createElement ( "div", "child"));
```

That seems to work fine. But, I need to determine the top position of the child to manage the content.

```
alert($('#child').position().top);
```

always returns 0; (not the value i want)

```
$('#child').click(function() {alert($(this).position().top);});
```

returns a non-zero amount. (this is the value I want).

So the question is; how do I determine the top position of a dymanically loaded element immediately after it's added?.

Comment: $('#parent').createElement or document.createElement ? Is this a mis-type?

Comment: Ref: *"That seems to work fine"*. It doesn't, really. Could you please update your question with a *working* [mcve]? The code you posted is far from working and it appears you're confusing methods available on DOM elements with jQuery methods.

Comment: yes it is a typo. thanks for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have not tested, but I would assume you need to "wait" until the element is really created. So, try to add short delay like this.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   alert($('#child').position().top);
}, 10);
```

Maybe a shorter delay like 0 or 1 instead of 10 may work, too.

Comment: Tried that. even raised the delay to 1 second. Doesn't appear to work

Comment: alert($('#child').attr("id")); returns the correct answer

Comment: thanks fvrab. you were on the right track. I was loading everything into jquery ui tab which turns out to be a hidden div until you click on the tab. So it was being created but not displayed so the metrics couldn't be determined